# The best way to do twist-like bridge?

Tags: mesh

I just wonder if there are any ideal solutions to do this without using lattice deform, etc. Thanks!

[image: Original | Normal | Twisted]

## Update:

I found I've been using a more regular and simple thing for illustration. Now what I really mean can be seen in the following image.

[image]

(This is quite puzzling me when using any current way I suppose, I mean, keep original loops un-twisted. but to twist the bridge.)

Comment: Sorry guys! I found I've been using a more regular and simple thing for illustrate. Now what I really mean can be seen in the updated image. P.S: I think the way you all suggested can well solve the old one. but... for the new one? Thanks and sorry again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Added twist offset option to the bridge tool [r58609](http://blender.markmail.org/thread/nlotlaujahnsh5q7) (will be available in 2.69 or any recent build).

Comment: Ah, this is even better, xie xie!

Answer (score 3):

This is possible to do without any addons or modifiers,

- Add a shape key
- Go into editmode
- Rotate one of the loops, say ~30deg
- Execute the Bridge Tool
- Remove the shape key.

now the bridge will be twisted.

*note that this won't work for twisting over 180deg.*

Comment: Thanks for an impressive "Shapekey" answer that I haven't even thought about! However, as I updated and commented to other guys, what I really mean is Not try changing any original loops. Just like what's seen in the outdated looptools addon, unforunately it doesn't support multi-bridge. I know you can do it if you think it's useful and worthy to, do you?  :)

Comment: @LeonCheung See [Best Place to put Feature Requests?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1190/290)

Comment: @Aldrik, I know. Believe me, the question really aims no feature request initially. Just want to know nice solutions for such case. Actually, I was asked by my friend, surprisingly it baffled me.

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to propose my own solution, which just came to my mind:

[image]

- Create one connected strip with desired edges by **W > Bridge Edge Loops**;
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert selection;
- Bridge again, set the number of cuts in the option panel, or hit <kbd>F6</kbd>.

IMHO, It could be a better and currently-existing way to do so. Advantage of this method would be:

1. Fast, direct, accurate and flexible;
2. Perfectly keep original loops the way as they were;
3. Effective for any simple or complicated loops to make twisted bridge.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the simple deform modifier. It has a few options for deformation, one of which is twisting.

If you simply add this modifier to an object that's pointing up, it'll twist it based upon the Deform angle:
[image: simple deform]

It should look something like this:

[image: result]

Comment: It's true for that certain scene. Sorry but what I really mean is to keep all original loops un-twisted. Please see the updated image. Thanks!

Comment: You want to twist it in a non-destructive way (i.e. it doesn't change in edit mode)?

Comment: Exactly. The most inefficient but universal way that I know is to manually join vertex pairs, then using loop cuts. Appreciated for any smarter way!

Answer (score 1):

If you go into user preferences (addons) and type loop tools into the search menu the loop tool menu will appear drop the the menu down and check the box to enable.

Go back to your 3D view and on the left hand menu (press <kbd>T</kbd>) you will now see a loop tools option. Drop the menu down and you will see an option called bridge click this open and you will see an option for twisting your mesh. Hope this helps.

Comment: Right. Lindsey, I knew this nice tool, and in fact, the 3rd column was made by it to illustrate. :P  It's surely good. However, comparing to the new bridge tool after 2.67, the addon doesn't support "multi-bridge", the great feature that Campbell has implemented.