# Wrap Geometry Around Mobius Strip

Tags: geometry

I have a geometry which is an extruded, rectangular plane with features on it, which I would like to wrap it around itself with a half twist in the way a mobius strip is constructed. Something similar to this:

[image: Mario Strip]

How would I go about constructing such a geometry?

Comment: This answer might help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32456/6204

Answer (score 2):

I start by making a few assumptions:

- Your geometry is not too prominent.
- It can get distorted quite a bit.

If these are true, you can use this trick.

There is one possible way. First you *start by baking the height* of the flat geometry. There are a number of ways to do this, see here for some possibilities:
[How to make a displacement map from existing 3d geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/how-to-make-a-displacement-map-from-existing-3d-geometry)

Armed with the height map you model the Möbius strip. *Unwrap it* (hint: you only get one side). Then add a *displacement modifier* to it (you probably also want a "Subdivision Surface* below. Level four or five should do it.). Set the Displace to use the height map. *Also set it to UV* (messed this up myself a few times) and *decrease it's strength*. You can finish with the combo solidify-edge split-subsurf lv.2. For optimum results set the shading to smooth.

I hope this helps.