# How to check if a mesh is a two-sided manifold?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I would like to check if a given mesh is a two-sided manifold rather than something like a Mobius strip. I can use [`bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=select_non_manifold#bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold) to check if it is a manifold. But how can I know whether it is two-sided?

For example, the procedure should be able to tell that the mesh created [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82480/how-to-make-a-mobius-strip) is not two-sided.