# How to control the Grid colours

Tags: 3d-view, customization

How can I control the colour of the lines in the grid?

So far I've figured out how to change the colour of the darker lines, but there are a set of lighter lines that appear every ten spaces.

[image] 
*Blender User Preferences - 3D View*

As shown in the screenshot there is a way to control the colour of the grid lines, I've experimented with this a little and the colour of the lighter grid lines appears to be linked to the colour that you set for the darker grid lines, but I would like to control this independently, perhaps making it a much brighter shade than the darker grid lines. Is this possible? I would hope that one of the other colours in there would control it, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't control the smaller grid-spacing values, these use an alpha value which is automatically calculated based on zoom level and the lightness of the grid-color (in orthographic mode).

Blender is calculating the color automatically and isn't giving you control.

Comment: I can't see how zoom level influences the the alpha value, how does that work? are you refering to the viewport zoom level  that is controllable via the mouse wheel? I've found a way to make the  lighter grid lines lighter by experimenting with the grid colour value, but i'm not sure what the rules are, setting it to hex 333333 give good results for me

Comment: Changing the zoom level of the viewport doesn't make any difference to the colour of the grid lines

Comment: It does in orthographic mode, edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the only way to get the lighter grid lines to have a greater contrast to the darker ones is to experiment with the the grid colour until it looks right.

After playing with the colour picker I found that the hex value `2C2C2C` causes the contrast to go the other way and make the lighter grid lines black, but this was not to my tastes so I settled with the hex value `333333`.

`333333` results in the darker grid lines being not so dark as to be invisible and the lighter grid lines to have a higher contrast to the darker ones. The default was `404040`.

[image]
*User Preferences - 3D View grid set to hex `33333`*

Below is what the grid looks like with that grid colour set to hex `333333`

[image]
*Blender - 3D View grid set to hex `33333`*

In the scaled screenshot it's hard to see the darker grid lines, but they are visible if you look at the image at full size.

Here is what the grid looks like with the grid colour set to `2C2C2C`

[image]
*Blender - 3D View grid set to hex `2C2C2C`*

Comment: Since you are going into a lot of effort to find how this works, the C source code is `source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_draw.c`, drawfloor() function. See how `col_grid_emphasise` is calculated.

Comment: @ideasman42 heres a link to the file used in the version of blender I have installed [view3d_draw.c](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/blender-2.68a-release/blender/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_draw.c) what would I need to do if I wanted to change the way that works and get it included in the official release?

Comment: first you should let us know the problem that you try to solve. Why the current behavior is not good. Making the change is fairly simple on its own.

Comment: @ideasman42 how does that work? is there a form on the blender site that needs to be filled out, or does one need to send an email to someone? Who decides which features are added to blender, is it possible for a random person to make a change to the source code and submit it for review and possible inclusion in the release?

Comment: We don't have a formal process: see, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests