# Audio Frame delay when pausing playback in 2.76 (already tried A-V Sync and matching frame length)

Tags: animation, video

I'm trying to animate some low poly shapes to a song on Blender 2.76 and when I finally went to compile everything my actions were all lagging behind the actual sounds.

When I went back into my keyframes and clicked just before the action the action and music would sync up perfectly, but when played from the beginning my actions would, again, be out of sync.

Initially I tried to re-load the program and click the <kbd>A-V Sync</kbd> button, then re-animated. This did not help.

I then made sure my audio and animation times finished on the same frame as per: [Blender's video and audio don't sync when editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/blenders-video-and-audio-dont-sync-when-editing) second comment, then re-animated. No luck.

Finally to see if there was a disparity between playback and music I baked the song to an F-Curve and sure enough when I played it from the beginning my music and f-curve matched up the whole way through. Alternately if I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> at any time or used <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to watch full screen, I would lose 15-25 frames between the music and the F-Curve. As you can imagine, this makes it really difficult to sync up my stuff.

Is this a bug I should be reporting to blender about a fault in the <kbd>A-V Sync</kbd> or am I just missing something simple altogether that I need to do beyond using <kbd>A-V Sync</kbd> and matching my ending frames?

P.s. My audio lags BEHIND the baked frames that it's supposed to be playing on.

Comment: Where is your audio playing from, the vse? Have you tried vse strip properties 》audio cache? Alternatively try changing the source file codec to something like flac or wav.

Comment: Yeah, VSE. I'll give that a shot, thanks for the lead.