# How to keep audio and video synced rendering an animation?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I am doing a voice over for my video. It’s suppose to be my first dev log. So my audio and video is completely separate. Why does the video render faster than the audio, how do I fix this? I am using blenders 2.8 video editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender's video and audio don't sync when editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/blenders-video-and-audio-dont-sync-when-editing)

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31471/audio-video-out-of-sync-in-rendered-video-but-not-in-vse?rq=1