# Can the sequencer strip view follow the scrubbing/playback bar?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When viewing a sequencer, and playing back using the timeline, the scrubber bar tracks the playback, but will run off the sequencer view. I can manually scroll to catch-up. Is there any way to set the UI so the scrubber bar is always in the sequence view when playing back?

Comment: I don't think there is, but you can easily zoom out so that all of the strips are visible by pressing the home key (top centre above the arrows)

Comment: Useful - but not quite what I want. I am now wandering if there's python code to do it (it sounds possible).

Comment: @DannyStaple I don't think it is, unfortunately. AFAIK there isn't any way to control the view from python.

Comment: Hmm - sounds like a enhancement request for the blender bug tracker...

Comment: Wow - requesting features from Blender is not an easy process.

Comment: @DannyStaple The bug tracker is meant for bugs, for feature requests see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1190/599

Comment: Yes I saw that - and didn't put it in there. I then saw the feature backlog and process, and decided this is probably a no hoper. I do not have time to implement it, or champion it being implemented.

Answer (score 3):

A [feature very similar to this](https://developer.blender.org/rBced4c5fe2260489f44a38498c3adfd3333215a26) was added quite recently (about an hour ago 
at the time of writing).

> Animation play: Follow feature. Enabled from playback menu in the
>   timeline.
>
> When enabled, ipo, dopesheet, NLA, timeline, clip and sequence editors
>   will follow the current frame during animation. When the cursor
>   reaches the end of the screen, then the next range of frames of the
>   same width is displayed.

<s>To use it you'll have to [grab a recent development build](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599). This feature should be in 2.74.</s>
This feature is now available in `timeline panel -> playback (next to the start frame field) -> follow`.

Answer (score 1):

There's an addon that might be able to help you.
Its called the VSE Quick functions addon.
You can find it at http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338598-Addon-WIP-VSE-Quick-functions-Snaps-Fades-Zoom-Parenting-Titling-Play-speed
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The option suggested above, included in the Blender bundle, will only keep track of the playhead if playback is started from the Timeline panel. (timeline panel -> playback (next to the start frame field) -> follow)

To follow the playback bar when playback is started from the Sequencer panel, instead of the Timeline panel, the 'VSE Quick Functions Plugin' is needed. It will add a button 'Follow Cursor' to the upper right of the sequencer's menu.

So the suggestions of both previous answers are right and eventually both are needed.