# Timeline navigation hotkeys

Tags: shortcut

When scrolling through the timeline, is there a way of locking the play head to the center whilst the strips, and other open windows, move, rather than the play head moving then having to keep manually readjusting the strip positions?

Or is there a shortcut key to center the play head if you've lost it, without pressing "home" an then zooming / re positioning / zooming / re positioning?

Iv'e just been through the [blender hotkeys](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Hotkeys/All) and cannot find anything.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8807/599 BTW, that list of hotkeys is for blender 3.7a (ancient). The best way to look at shortcuts is in the user prefs (Ctrl Alt U > Input). This way they will always be up to date.

Comment: Though [this](http://waldobronchart.github.io/ShortcutMapper/#Blender) looks like a pretty nice interactive way to look at them too.. Anyway, there are currently no operators which do what you want. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The closest there currently is in official blender is [*follow playback*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24288/599), which will at least keep the playback head in the view.

Answer (score -1):

Numpad 0 centers the player head in the timeline.