# Fixed play head moving strips

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to fix the play head in the center of the VSE, and have the strips moving as the video plays?

- If it is possible then how do I do it?
- If it's not possible in blender, is there a script to do it?
- If there's not a script to do it, then could someone please give this
  novice scripter some pointers on how to do this.

Comment: Unfortunatly it's not possible atm, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8807/599.

Comment: Oh no, This would be so useful.

Comment: Maybe try using blender python and set the position of your strip equal to your current frame...

Comment: How would that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?338598-Addon-WIP-VSE-Quick-functions-Snaps-Fades-Zoom-Parenting-Titling-Play-speed

This addon already has that function