# Is there a tool similar to maya's "edit edge flow" in blender

Tags: modeling

I personally enjoy modeling in blender more than maya, but this one tool is so extremely helpful. It should be included in blender if there isnt something similar already. Is there a place where I can suggest tools?

Heres an example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-G7UblIjTs

Comment: For feature requests see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1190/599

Comment: Here is some nice tool about it
https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/EdgeFlow

Comment: Question: Is there a tool similar to maya's “edit edge flow” in blender? Answer: yes. Here is addon that called EdgeFlow. [https://blenderartists.org/t/it-is-finally-here-edge-flow-set-flow-for-blender-benjamin-saunder/1128115](https://blenderartists.org/t/it-is-finally-here-edge-flow-set-flow-for-blender-benjamin-saunder/1128115)

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly, but there are some tools which you can use to get similar results in specific situations.

### Shrink/Fatten (Scale along normals)

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

### Smooth subdivide

Change *Smoothness* in the redo panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>) after subdividing

[image]

### Smooth loop cut

Change Smoothness in the redo panel after cutting, or set the smoothness while positioning the cut with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd> (the smooth value is displayed in the header).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this (even more efficiently then in the video I think)

- Select an edge ring (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>)
- Edge Menu -> Edge Loops (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>)
- Edge Menu -> Subdivide (Adjust smooth)

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for the first example in the video (I haven't found any tools which can do that.. As a matter of fact, this is what I did for the second gif in my answer). It also doesn't work as nicely for editing existing edges..

Comment: What exactly doesn't work well?

Comment: Sliding an entire edge loop like in the beginning of the OP's video. Here's an example animation: http://pasteall.org/pic/73242. It kind of bulges and deforms along the minor radius, instead of maintaining a nice circle.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then click <kbd>V</kbd> (Smooth Vertices)
It works more like a mix between "Average Vertices" and "Edit Edge Flow", but it's the closest I've found that's useful on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

**there is no tool like max or maya..**

**Shrink/Fatten** = Manual (not 100% correct and trying to fix more than one takes long time)

**Smooth subdivide** = you must add loop.. you cant fix older edges or vertexes.

**Smooth loop cut** = same as smooth subdive.. useless for old edges and vertexes

i have no i dea why we have no set flow / edge flow tool. trying to fix with manually is sucks..

Answer (score 0):

Change the Smoothness of the Loop Cut.
While I haven't found out the optimal setting, smoothness 0.5 seems to be a nice solution.

If it is tedeous to set the smoothness everytime, you can set it from the User Prefs too.[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use *Bridge Edge Loops* and its *Smoothness* factor.

1. Delete the face loop where you want to add an edge loop.
2. Select edge loops which were holding that face loop, run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*.
3. In the Last Operator panel (on the *Toolshelf* or from <kbd>F6</kbd>) change settings for *Number of Cuts* and *Smoothness*.

[image]