# Is there really no way to add edge loops with maintaining geometry?

Tags: modeling

I often come into situations where I would need more geometry when modeling using subdivision surface. Maya has a tool for that. It works by adding edges by subdividing but still maintaining the form of the mesh. Here is a link showing how it works:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVX_II7VQxI&t=130s

Here is a picture hopefully clearing my question:

[image]

Comment: ctrl + r???????

Comment: This: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13545/is-there-a-tool-similar-to-mayas-edit-edge-flow-in-blender?rq=1 might also help

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: the question isn't about how to add edge loops, but how to add them in a way that they don't change the surface when working with subsurf. Normally, edge loops with subsurf make the edges sharper which isn't always intended. (Note that the subsurf modifier is just an easy way to visualize the effect)

Comment: @Sensimas If the duplicate question isn't what you meant then you need to [edit] your question and add additional details to explain how your question differs.

Comment: This is NOT duplicate, watch the video linked.

Comment: The last shape was adjusted manually (not mathematically) so it differs from the first one, but the idea is to add geometry while the shape remains the same when subdivided. The tool is creating new geometry to match the original geometry  with edges right where you need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any information on the web regarding that sort of tool in Blender therefore I conclude it does not exist. However I think the workaround might work in some situations depending on your needs. Here is what I used:

- select your mesh
- alt +c (convert to) -> mesh from curve/meta/subd/text
- cleverly use the edges you need for your shape and remove the ones that does not affect it

Hope it helps.