# Is there a way to assign a custom wireframe color for objects?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I deal with quite a few objects with interesting edges, and it's becoming impossible to see which element belongs to which object, when they all have the same color. Is there a way to set custom wireframe colors?

Comment: Not at the moment, there is [work](https://developer.blender.org/D458) being done to the wireframes, but currently it is not possible without some workarounds.

Comment: Strange, Blender is so good at quite a few complex operations, but a few of the vary basic ones are lacking. This is certainly one of them.

Comment: This shouldn't be hard to implement since Blender already has support for multiple wire colors. Grouped objects have green and objects with keyframes yellow wire colors.

Comment: Link on where to post [Feature Requests](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests)

Comment: @David seems like that patch is abandoned. Shame.

Comment: this is a video about how to change wireframe color https://youtu.be/fPBpkAHje4c

Answer (score 14):

Since Blender 2.8 there is an option for colored wireframes.

At the top right of the viewport, select "Wireframe" shading, then under the shading dropdown arrow ("Viewport Shading") you can set Color to Single, Object or Random.

[image: pointer to the menu element]

Comment: at the top right of what?

Comment: @endolith, I've added a picture showing the relevant dropdown option. The shading modes {wireframe, solid, material preview, and rendered} are the buttons with spheres to the left of the dropdown arrow. You can pick the object color in the menu on the right (object properties is the orange box with corners, and the color setting is under "viewport display"). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Too bad it can't assign random dark colors while still highlighting the selected object with a bright color

Comment: it is on object mode .. i am looking for edit mode

Answer (score 2):

When I have say 3 objects that I am working with and one object I am aligning to another the object is silhouetted in my case with a 'orange' outline against all the grey. (This colour can be adjusted in preferences) If the object is in edit mode again the wireframe is a different colour.

You also can use the align / snap to feature.

I personally do agree though that multi colour assignment to wireframes would be useful in many situations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange :) Your response is more of a discussion than an actual answer. Thus, it would be more useful as a comment to the original question than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a Tip since colored wireframes will not be coded into blender.
Select your object press M move it to another layer, there you can work alone on them. in the next version of blender this layer and grouping system will be more advanced. So i think thats the way to workaround this.

Comment: Why do we need workarounds/hacks/tricks at all? Couldn't it be done in the _obvious, natural_ way to begin with, like in other 3D modelling programs? ;p  How can I tell the wireframes apart if they're all grey? Layers won't fix that, since it is often the case that I need to see both objects at the same time (e.g. when I'm aligning one wireframe with another), but be able to tell them apart at the same time. And colour for wireframes is the only way that can solve that.

Comment: It has been a very active discussed topic in Blenders pasts, and eventually, it didn't got in. Most people overall were against it, if also the main developers don't want it (and i'm sure they have lots of contacts in this fields), then its not going to happen. I dont know the reasons, but i asume that many collors would just bloat the screen, as allready has fixed colors width certain meanings. So unless you hack Blender and built it in its not going to happen. 
BTW you can give meshes a color, see object props

Comment: I know that we can assign colours to the objects in the viewport. (And strangely enough, this suddenly does not "bloat the screen with colours" :q )  The problem is, I can't assign colours to the wireframes in the edit mode, which makes it unable to tell them apart, because they're all grey. It's not about layering, because I need to see all of them at the same time to properly align them with respect to each other. But it is REALLY hard when they're all the same colour. And I really can't imagine who with a sane mind would object against it and why. There aren't any real alternatives.

Comment: Yes i understand, but unless you get into development make your own (blender is opensource)there is no chance of that going to happen, its just not available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add custom color to wireframe:

1. In the wireframe modifier section, change *Material Offset* to "1"
2. Go to the textures, add a new texture and make it the same color as your wireframe
3. Then change *Pass Index* to "1"

It should be working now.

Comment: I don't think this is what the user was asking. I believe he meant the viewport object color while in wireframe shading mode. Your technique is geared more towards rendering, and requires changing geometry with additional modifiers.