# Change object's wire display colour

Tags: color, collections, wireframe

Can the object's wire display colours be changed from black to a colour that I assign?
I have set all objects in a collection to display as wires, but I don't see how I can change the colour of their display. Changing the theme is not something I am after, I just want to differentiate between this collection and any other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to assign a custom wireframe color for objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41702/is-there-a-way-to-assign-a-custom-wireframe-color-for-objects)

Comment: Unfortunately not, wireframe displays different from Wire display. Wire display does not seem to take these viewport settings into account.

Comment: Please edit your ask to include a full screenshot of the issue that shows a wire display (not wireframe).

Comment: I have come to understand that this is not possible currently.

Comment: @Hologram: what is the difference between wire display and wireframe display? for me it looks the same...am i missing something?

Comment: Object > Viewport Display > Display as Wire, you'll notice when you do. There is a checkbox to display the wireframe, which overlays the object with a wireframe. Wire display is treated similar to a bounding box display. It appears to be similar, but for Blender, it is not.