# Where do I find the maximum node?

Tags: node-editor

A lot of people recommend to use the maximum node for glass setup, but I can't find that node. Nothing comes up when I search for it.

Where do I find it?

[image]

Comment: I'm always very annoyed that drop-downs aren't included in search results. I even opened a feedback tickets with Blender... Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55919/how-do-you-find-the-nodes-youre-looking-for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no discrete "Maximum" node, *Maximum* is the name of one of the many operations in the *Math* node. The displayed title is adjusted according to the chosen operations

[According to the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/math.html) the *Math* node contains the following operations:

- Functions

  - **Add** | The sum of the two values.
  - **Subtract** | The difference between the two values.
  - **Multiply** | The product of the two values.
  - **Divide** | The division of the first value by the second value.
  - **Multiply** Add | The sum of the product of the two values with Addend.
  - **Power** | The Base raised to the power of Exponent.
  - **Logarithm** | The log of the value with a Base as its base.
  - **Square** Root | The square root of the value.
  - **Inverse** Square Root | One divided by the square root of the value.
  - **Absolute** | The input value is read with without regard to its sign. This turns negative values into positive values.
  - **Exponent** | Raises Euler’s number to the power of the value.
- Comparison

  - **Minimum** | Outputs the smallest of the input values.
  - **Maximum** | Outputs the largest of two input values.
  - **Less Than** | Outputs 1.0 if the first value is smaller than the second value. Otherwise the output is 0.0.
  - **Greater Than** | Outputs 1.0 if the first value is larger than the second value. Otherwise the output is 0.0.
  - **Sign** | Extracts the sign of the input value. All positive numbers will output 1.0. All negative numbers will output -1.0. And 0.0 will output 0.0.
  - **Compare** | Outputs 1.0 if the difference between the two input values is less than or equal to Epsilon.
  - **Smooth Minimum** | Smooth Minimum.
  - **Smooth Maximum** | Smooth Maximum.
- Rounding

  - **Round** | Round the input value to the nearest integer.
  - **Floor** | Rounds the input value down to the nearest integer.
  - **Ceil** | Rounds the input value up to the nearest integer.
  - **Truncate** | Outputs the integer part of the value.
  - **Fraction** | Fraction.
  - **Modulo** | Outputs the remainder once the first value is divided by the second value.
  - **Wrap** | Outputs a value between Min and Max based on the absolute difference between the input value and the nearest integer multiple of Max less than the value.
  - **Snap** | Round the input value to down to the nearest integer multiple of Increment.
  - **Ping-pong** | The output value is moved between 0.0 and the Scale based on the input value.
- Trigonometric

  - **Sine** | The Sine of the input value.
  - **Cosine** | The Cosine of the input value.
  - **Tangent** | The Tangent of the input value.
  - **Arcsine** | The Arcsine of the input value.
  - **Arccosine** | The Arccosine of the input value.
  - **Arctangent** | The Arctangent of the input value.
  - **Arctan2** | Outputs the Inverse Tangent of the first value divided by the second value measured in radians.
  - **Hyperbolic Sine** | The Hyperbolic Sine of the input value.
  - **Hyperbolic Cosine** | The Hyperbolic Cosine of the input value.
  - **Hyperbolic Tangent** | The Hyperbolic Tangent of the input value.
- Conversion

  - **To Radians** | Converts the input from degrees to radians.
  - **To Degrees** | Converts the input from radians to degrees.

Add a new *Converter > Math* node then set its operation to *Maximum*.

[image]