# Can't find the Scale node

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

[image]

[image]

Hi i'm following youtube tutorial but my blender(3.6) doesn't have 'Scale' node and only have these 3 nodes.. i tried all my best but it doesn't work same way.. the tutorial video made by blender 3.4 beta and i also download same version and couldn't find neither.
Help me..

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125169/where-do-i-find-the-maximum-node/

Answer (score 4):

The node is called *Vector Math*, and it is set to the *Scale* operation.