# Blender VSE Issues and Future

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio, frame-rate

I am now done mastering the learning curve for the VSE and done with my first video project (20min, 5 channels, 100+ clips different format, pictures, transitions etc). I switched from years in KDEenlive to Blender because of the positive reviews regarding OS video editor choices and instability and linux only limitation of KDEnlive.

Now it turned out that Blender VSE was mostly rockstable and has a nice "video building feel". But in the current state (2.78) it has major and minor issues that would prevent me from trying another path again and I would like to know if there is anyone either helping me with the issues or working actively on fixing them.

Major ones:

(1) The rendering is terribly slow and does not seem to use more than one core. h264 rendering on my SSD/16GB/skylake i7 is more than 4x faster in Handbrake (same codec, same file). KDEenlive is way faster with ffmpeg too. I checked all the info here and other forums on it. No luck. Need 3h for those 20mins. Rendering picture movement and transitions is even worse - 2-3  FPS only.

(2) Sometimes some seemingly random audio clips in the big video project are not rendered. Everything is fine in the VSE, plays fine there. In the rendered video there is first sound then when some clips should fade in there is silence. Later on when other clips come in sound comes again. WTF - i found no solution on the web to it. I could just reimport the clips again doing keyframe fiddling again etc pp. This is a killer problem.

(3) Going back through your user modifications needs endless ctrl-y/z keytrokes because it seems to register non modifying user input as zooms/moves somehow as steps... weird.

Minor ones:

(4) Frame rate conversion issues. I could not make some clips withe different framerate (25 instead of 50 project fps) work in VSE. If I did a speed adjustment (2x) it played with  half speed, if I did none it played double speed, but 1.5x -> 1.5 speed. A nasty bug but I should have transformed everything with handbrake prior to importing them in VSE.

(5) A pity that there is no easy and in the strip editor visible "gamma cross for audio" - or a coupling option with it. you always have to mess with keyframes (or crossfade sounds) and they get messed up very easily when you move your audio clips.

(6) No audio correction - appreciate the volume and pitch modifiers but some basic filtering would be nice.

(7) Waveform drawing does not seem to be affected by the volume setting though this would be a very easy enhancement (to level out volume differences)

(8) Imported photos seem to be scaled and therefore deformed to the VSE aspect ratio and there is no other fix than to transform them again. There is also no slideshow pan and zoom automatism like in kdenlive, you have to do it by hand - but its doable with keyframes.

---

All in all I want to applaude the blender creators that they did such a capable video editor "en passant" and the community seems to be very helpful and professional.
With some issues resolved and some features added it could become the VLC of video editors.
Anyone in the know if there is a plan for that?

Best regards,
George

Comment: Best place to put bug reports? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: Best Place to put Feature Requests? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests

Comment: Assuming no one on this site is a Blender Dev, I would say no. We don't know what their plans are

Comment: I have done lots of editing in the vse and 1 and 8 are the worst. I have written a script for 6. 2 and 3 never happened to me before. I would vote to close this question. Please ask separate questions (all your points are valid as a separate post). There may be solutions or add on which you don't knwo about yet.

Comment: Hello, my question was to confirm either something a bug and/or post it as a feature request. Thank you for your comments where to put both and also for comments that confirm my observations or point to solutions.