# How do you make a movie loop in the sequencer?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a movie file that I want to loop thousands of times. It's a one-second background loop behind a podcast.

I tried stretching the video strip past the end of the content, but it just produces a still image of the final frame when I do that.

Comment: you can duplicate the strip, as last resort...

Comment: I think this could be a valid feature request... see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests

Comment: Do it with an animated GIF?  They loop seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Work Fine 2.79
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Loop_Media

"Pick a Scene, Image, or Movie strip in the Video Sequence Editor, and use the Strip menu to find the Loop Media operator. A speed effect strip will be created to accomplish the looping effect"

Excelent Script

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make your strip with ffmpeg like this (for 1 minute):

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i movie.mp4 -t 1:00.00 looped_movie.mp4
```

An use the strip `looped_movie.mp4` in Blender VSE

Comment: (a shame there is not a strip effect to do that inside Blender)