# How to add an animated time controlled text effect to the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to edit videos for my dance group. What I'd like to be able to do is have an overlay that I can set the B.P.M (beats per minute) and I can display a simple metronome + counter over the video.

I notice that there is a text effect in the VSE

[image]

Is there any way to hook a callback based on the frame count that can change the text as the video progresses? This might be able to get me what I need.

**Progress**

I've discovered that I can do

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

and the current frame count is output to the console. Now I would need to calculate and inject some text into the VSE

**First real attempt**

```
import bpy

def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)
    ob = bpy.data.objects['TimeCode']
    ob['Text']=scene.frame_current


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

where I have a text effect added to the VSE and defined as

[image]

but I get console errors as

> File "C:\Users\bradp\OneDrive\Video\NewStyle
>   C\choreo1.blend\Counter", line 7, in my_handler KeyError:
>   'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "TimeCode" not found'

Comment: You could try out the TextFX addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding and slightly correcting the answer by [bradgonesurfing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/47771/bradgonesurfing), you *can* do this without any addons.  First, create the text strip in the Video Sequence Editor and give it a name like "Timer".  Now, create a Python script similar to this:

```
# TimerScript.py
# Arrange to update a VSE text strip to show elapsed time.

# Put this file next to your .blend file, open it in the Blender
# Text Editor view, and use "Text -> Run Script" to run it.  It
# will be active for the duration of the Blender editing session.

import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
obj = scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all['Timer']
fps = scene.render.fps

def recalculate_text(scene):
    # Number of frames since the start of the text strip.
    frames = scene.frame_current - obj.frame_start

    # Divide to get hours, minutes, seconds, and hundredths of a second.
    seconds_float = frames / fps
    seconds = int(seconds_float)
    hundredths = int((seconds_float - seconds) * 100)
    minutes = int(seconds / 60)
    seconds -= minutes * 60
    hours = int(minutes / 60)
    minutes -= hours * 60

    # Combine as a string.
    time_string = "{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}.{:02d}".format(
        hours, minutes, seconds, hundredths)

    # Update the text object.    
    #print('Recalc: ' + time_string)
    obj.text = time_string

# This is used when moving between frames during editing.
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(recalculate_text)

# This is used during animation rendering.
bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(recalculate_text)
```

Open the script in the Blender Text Editor (you can create it there in the first place) and run it via "Text → Run Script".

The slightly tricky bit, and the correction to Brad's answer, is you need to install this *both* as a pre-frame handler and a pre-render handler.  If you only set it as pre-frame, then the update will not happen when rendering animations!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Animation Nodes to do this very easily:

[image: Node Tree]

You can do all sort of editing like:

[image: Node Tree 2]

The Frame Rate input is hidden by default, show it like this:

[image: Node Tree 3]

Comment: This looks great. However I have blender 2.79 and my node editor window is a little different. Next to the node menu I only have 3 icons not 4 and the far left one you have selected I don't have. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you installed the animation nodes addon?

Comment: No. I guess that will be the problem

Comment: Got it. Solution rocks :)

Comment: How do I get the FPS as a node here. I need to calculate the real time as I did in my script answer. The time info only gives the current frame.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Updated the answer.

Comment: I tried that but the output from Frame Rate is some wierd number **3267** or something. I know from experimenting that the the frame rate was very close to 30 FPS. What is the conversion here?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing hmmm, it works fine for me. How did you view this number, using a viewer node?

Comment: Let me check when I'm home again tonight. There was something strange about the number and it was big. Essentially what I want is the real time value. time = FrameCount / FPS

Comment: You mention here in the comments that `Animation Nodes` needs to be installed but your answer does not explain this. Could you update your answer with some explanation on what this is?

Answer (score 3):

The following script displays the frame count as an overlay

```
import bpy


def my_handler(scene):
    print("Frame Change", scene.frame_current)
    bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].sequence_editor.sequences_all["TimeCode"].text=str(scene.frame_current)


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

The path to the data object was retrieved from the tooltip

[image]

Comment: Nice. Could expand this for a generic case for any strip in scene named "TimeCode". .Would need to check `seq = scene.sequence_editor`  is not None, and `seq.sequences_all.get("TimeCode")` is not None.

Comment: Actually this does't work as it only works in manual mode. When I create a rendering the script is not called. No idea why.

Comment: lol, see what you mean.  Does appear to work in render (still) image.  Suggest adding a text object to scene and using frame change handler to animate its body.

Comment: The reason this script does not work during rendering is you also need to add it as a `render_pre` handler.  See [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165951/88108) for a little elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about scripting. Try to answer it with the manual way. 
From my understaning, it is about rendering a sequence of numbers and clamp it into one minute.

---

If anything fancy is not needed. **Frame counter** can be generated from **Metadata**.

*Properties > Render > Metadata > Stamp Output*

[image: Render Frame count in frame]

- Setup a empty Scene and set *End Frame = BPM*
- Render the empty scene with *Metadata ON* and *Transparent*.
- Overlay the *clip* to the dancing video, Transform the clip to *one minute* long with **Speed Control**. and *Loop* it over.

---

For video looping, please refer to:

[How do you make a movie loop in the sequencer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76085/how-do-you-make-a-movie-loop-in-the-sequencer)