# Is there a way to loop a movie that is also transformed in Blender's VSE?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video, movie-clip-editor, looping

I'm attempting to loop an .mkv while also modifying the video with a Transform strip.  Here are the details:

- Video is 93 frames
- Total desired frames for looped video is 705
- The Transform strip scales the video along the X axis, while also translating the whole video across the visible canvas, parallel to the X axis.  This moves the video from right to left as the video plays.

I followed the thread [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76085/how-do-you-make-a-movie-loop-in-the-sequencer?newreg=2e37ddf461ce49428bcce6dc719f32be), however I cannot get the video to translate more than a few pixels from it's start position.  About half way into the video strip, the video ceases to display.  No adjustments in the size of the video strip fixes this. The only alternative I can think of would be to manually loop the video ~7.5 times in a separate .m file, export it, and then import it.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: personally I would create the 705 frame video first externally and then transform it. But it should work by just duplicating the video repeatedly, preferably in a Meta strip.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just duplicating the images in a video file.  I'll try the use of a metal strip

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.