# How can I make my animation video repeat several times so it is a loop?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, video, loop

My animation video after the rendering is only 4 seconds long tho I want it to repeat several times so I can choose how many seconds the video should have.

My animation video has 120 keyframes it took long to render it with Cycles but unfortunately it only takes 4 seconds and this is too short I would want to have like 20-30 seconds.

Comment: hello, use the VSE, import you images, it will create a strip, duplicate the strip, render?

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING BRO!!!! thank you so so much omg it really worked i was searching for lots of days but with your help it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the *VSE (Video Sequencer)* window, import you images with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Image/Sequence*, it will create a strip, duplicate the strip with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, render.

Comment: Is it possible to repeat it without duplicate, because duplicate manually is boring.

Comment: Here is a similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76085/how-do-you-make-a-movie-loop-in-the-sequencer it seems like there's no tool to repeat in the VSE, you need a script