# AMD RYZEN Particles and Physics Simulations optimization needed

Tags: particles, physics, optimization

teddiursa here.

I bought AMD RYZEN 1700 and it helps a lot with cutting down rendering and compositing time. But it becoming more apparent that Blender's Particles and Physics Simulation does not harness the greater number of cores and threads that R7 1700 provided. Is there any way to improve blender's particles and physics simulations cpu utilization. I'm thinking about specifically donating towards blender's particles and physics simulations, does such option exist?

Comment: This site is not related with the blender foundation or the developers of blender. To request features and find out how to contribute please contact them directly: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact#Mailing_Lists

Comment: Please read through this link to find the appropiate way to get in touch with developers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests

Answer (score 3):

Physics calculations are extremely hard to thread and there is, as far as I know, no magic setting to change this. Think of it this way. Rendering you can do frame one and frame ten at the same time. Frame ten doesn't depend on the result of frame one. In physics simulations core two can't start work till core one finishes since it needs its data. Their is some performance improvements as some of the calculations can be threaded, but overall processor speed is the far more important factor.