# thumbnails display mode, can we change pangram?

Tags: text-editor

When I open the font libray, in the thumbnails display mode, I asked me if there is any solution to change the language pangram of the representation the font:
I mean: can we change, for exemple, the sentence "AaBbCc The quick brown fox..." into ; "GgOoDd Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs"?

Thank's a lot!

[image: English langage pangram]

Comment: I don't think so... why would it be so useful in a font preview?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suspected that it was not easy to do it. Well, as I love typography, it would have allowed me to compare instantly, how is a letter in capital compared to another, in a whole folder. it's very handy for making choices, or to recognize a used font.
In spite of everything, I really like the Blender fonts menu display mode... it's almost perfect!

Comment: ok, you could issue a feature request, then, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests

Comment: is it a good or a bad idea? but I was asking me if it was possible to change the pangram in the Blender fonts menu thumbnails display mode.
my first idea was a script, TPangram.py ; it would add a windows text box called "TPangram" (TransformPangram.py) in the font menu tab, then you tape the texte inside, then it appear in the Thumbnails display mode.
A second option ; there is no possibility to type texte, but only to switch between differents pangram (4 or 5 possibilities perhaps).
Is this a mess or easy? however, it's not a priority in Blender, but it can help a lot of creative people.