# I have an idea of blender plugin where can i post it

Tags: python, scripting

I have an idea of blender plugin [**in details**] where can i post this idea hope some one make it real

Comment: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an idea and not question about problem in Blender itself.

Comment: related: [Best Place to put Feature Requests?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests)