# Drag and drop multiple images in Node Editor?

Tags: node-editor, import

I can't drop multiple images in Node editor, it only create one node with the first image and others are ignored, any idea ?

Comment: That's a limitation. Suggest to put a feature request: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests/1211

Comment: I don't know if this is why you want to put multiple textures in the shader editor, but if you want to add multiple textures for a principled setup (Albedo, Normal map, Roughness, Displacement, etc.) you can use the node wrangler add-on and either use CTRL SHIFT T when you have your principled shader selected, or on the right panel with "N" and then Node Wrangler > Add Principled Setup.