# Control-Click on a Mac?

Tags: shortcut, osx

How can I <kbd>Control</kbd> Click on a Mac? I mean holding the <kbd>Control</kbd> key and clicking to get the <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> functionality. I know that I can use a right-click mouse, but I like using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is to go to system prefs on MacOS and go to mouse or on macbook trackpad and select point and click settings and then secondary click and adjust any necessary settings

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question. Right-click is set up fine in my macOS System Preferences. My question is: Blender does not respond to ctrl-click, only a physical right-click with the Magic Mouse. Every other Mac app reads ctrl-click as right-click.

Comment: In that case this sounds like a feature that hasnt been implemented into bledner yet, so i think you should take this to the request a feature section to blender.org

Comment: I can't find the place to suggest features, only report bugs

Comment: i found another question that has some good answers for requesting features https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests